Find objects of a certain length inside the object
I need to go through the json object and find keys-objects, keys-arrays whose size matches a given value.
I can't understand where to set the conditions.
function traverse(obj, size) {
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj[key] != null) {
            traverse(obj[key]);
            if (Object.keys(obj[key]).length > size) {
                console.log(key);
            } else if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
                if (obj[key].length > size) { 
                    console.log(key);
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}

I've tried rearranging the if conditions, but it doesn't give any good results
Sample Test Object
let objTest = {
    "id": "66100c8e58d0a40e97ce7753",
    "createdBy": "crm1",
    "attributes": {
        "accountsInfoMessages": [{
            "valueOzb": "Mijozning holati yoritilgan. Hisob yaratish mumkin emas. Mijoz ma'lumotlarini to'ldiring. Buning uchun \"Kartochkani tanrirlash\" tugmasini bosing.",
            "code": "notCreateAccount",
        }, {
            "valueOzb": "Mijozning holati yoritilgan. Hisob yaratish mumkin emas. Mijoz ma'lumotlarini to'ldiring. Buning uchun \"Kartochkani tanrirlash\" tugmasini bosing.",
            "code": "notCreateAccount",
        }, {
            "valueOzb": "Mijozning holati yoritilgan. Hisob yaratish mumkin emas. Mijoz ma'lumotlarini to'ldiring. Buning uchun \"Kartochkani tanrirlash\" tugmasini bosing.",
            "code": "notCreateAccount",
        }],
        "selectedCardProduct": null,
        "homePageId": null,
        "branch": null,
        "customerId": "1111",
        "selectForCurrencyTest": "111",
        "selectForFiltersCardType": {
            "values": [{
                "code": "01",
                "valueOzb": "HUMO"
            }, {
                "code": "02",
                "valueOzb": "UzCard",
            }, {
                "code": "03",
                "valueOzb": "Visa"
            }],
        },
        "selectForCurrency": [{
            "valueOzb": "Andor pesetasi",
            "code": "ADP"
        }, {
            "code": "AED",
            "valueOzb": "Birlashgan Arab Amirliklari dirhami"
        }, {
            "valueOzb": "Afg'ani",
            "code": "AFA"
        }, ]
    },
    "selectForCurrency": "Test"
}


please add some data as well. and the wanted result.

I've corrected some parts of your function as per my understanding. This should work. If it doesn't, let me know in the comments what error/bug you encounter. Preferably, add an instance/simplified example of the object you're traversing to your question.
EDIT: Here's the final draft of a tested solution:


/* Test Data: */
const testObject = {
  owner: 'John Doe',
  prices: [200, 450, -400, 3000, -650, -130, 70, 1300],
  interestRate: 1.2, // %
  pin: 1111,
  nullVal: null,
  objOuter: {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3,
    arr1: [200, 450, -650],
    inner: {
      uno: 1,
      dos: 2,
      tres: 3,
      arr2: [-400, 3000],
      innermost: {
        ich: 1,
        ni: 2,
        san: 3,
        arr3: [-130, 70, 1300],
      },
    },
  },
};

/* Function: */
function traverse(obj, size) {
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (!val) continue;
    if (Array.isArray(val) && val.length > size) {
      console.log(key);
      val.forEach(function (el, i) {
        if (typeof el === 'object') traverse(el, size);
      });
    }
    if (typeof val === 'object' && !Array.isArray(val) && Object.keys(val).length > size) {
      console.log(key);
      traverse(val, size);
    }
  }
}
traverse(testObject, 3); // Function call




Thank you. Looks like it's working. The problem was only if value is null, when checking for an array - Object.keys(val) could not convert null.
I added a check for null
if (typeof val === 'object' && val != null && !Array.isArray(val) && Object.keys(val).length > size)

You don't need to check for 'null' values because the condition (typeof val === "object") takes care of it. If val is an object type, its value will not be null even if it is empty.
Just like how console.log({}); and console.log([]); do not print null.
If val is an empty object/array, the condition that checks its size/length will be false and val will be ignored.

Without the check, it throws 'TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object ' on Object.keys(val).
I have attached a sample object.

Yes. That seems to be the case. To fix it properly, I suggest adding this line: if (!val) continue; to the top of the for-of loop in the function. I'm adding this line in the final edit to the answer.

You are calling traverse with only one argument.
if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj[key] != null) {
    traverse(obj[key]); // here !
     //... rest of the code
}


it should be
traverse(obj[key], size);

Please privide object example with desired result to verify the logic


You should pass the arguments to the recursive calls
You could add an accumulator to collect the result



let objTest={id:"66100c8e58d0a40e97ce7753",createdBy:"crm1",attributes:{accountsInfoMessages:[{valueOzb:"Mijozning holati yoritilgan. Hisob yaratish mumkin emas. Mijoz ma'lumotlarini to'ldiring. Buning uchun \"Kartochkani tanrirlash\" tugmasini bosing.",code:"notCreateAccount"},{valueOzb:"Mijozning holati yoritilgan. Hisob yaratish mumkin emas. Mijoz ma'lumotlarini to'ldiring. Buning uchun \"Kartochkani tanrirlash\" tugmasini bosing.",code:"notCreateAccount"},{valueOzb:"Mijozning holati yoritilgan. Hisob yaratish mumkin emas. Mijoz ma'lumotlarini to'ldiring. Buning uchun \"Kartochkani tanrirlash\" tugmasini bosing.",code:"notCreateAccount"}],selectedCardProduct:null,homePageId:null,branch:null,customerId:"1111",selectForCurrencyTest:"111",selectForFiltersCardType:{values:[{code:"01",valueOzb:"HUMO"},{code:"02",valueOzb:"UzCard"},{code:"03",valueOzb:"Visa"}]},selectForCurrency:[{valueOzb:"Andor pesetasi",code:"ADP"},{code:"AED",valueOzb:"Birlashgan Arab Amirliklari dirhami"},{valueOzb:"Afg'ani",code:"AFA"},]},selectForCurrency:"Test"};

function traverse(obj, size, key = null, result = []) {
  if(Array.isArray(obj)){
    obj.forEach((item,i) => traverse(item, size, i, result));
    obj.length > size && key && result.push(key);
  } else if (obj && typeof obj === "object") {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys.forEach(key => traverse(obj[key], size, key, result));
    keys.length > size && key && result.push(key);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(traverse(objTest, 1));




Thank you for your reply. The function returns an empty array. I have not been able to debug where the error is. I have attached a test object.
